# How to use `extends` with `gitlab-runner exec`

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a `.gitlab-ci.yaml` with the `extends` directive, which works on the gitlab-ci, but I cannot test it with `gitlab-runner exec`, it looks like the `extends` is ignored by `gitlab-runner`.

I have two files, like:

```
# .2extend.yml
.job2extend:
  image: some/docker/img
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo do things with "${myvar}"
```

and

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml
include:
  - project: 'project/to/extend'
    ref: master
    file: '.2extend.yml'

myjob:
  extends: .job2extend
  variables:
    myvar: 'My Variable'
```

This is the error I'm having:

```
$ gitlab-runner exec docker myjob
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=29785 revision=45d9c1d6 version=12.4.0~beta.1935.g45d9c1d6
FATAL: missing 'script' for job
```

The job I am extending from, have both `script` and `image` directives.

I have come to [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3794) which has the same problem as I do.

So, there is workaround to do this while the issue is not solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `gitlab-runner exec` has some limitations, before using this functional please check with [Limitations of gitlab-runner exec](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#limitations-of-gitlab-runner-exec)

As you can see for now `extends` is not listed in the table.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is because the .gitlab-ci.yml file of the project does not have a script block at the root level (for example like this)

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml    
include:
  - project: 'project/to/extend'
    ref: master
    file: '.2extend.yml'

myjob:
  extends: .job2extend
  variables:
    myvar: 'My Variable'

script:
  - myjob
```